# How to install Windows Updates from command line without third party scripts

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I am aware of PSWindowsUpdate but this is a third party script that is not created by Microsoft.  For the more security conscious of us out there, I am wondering how to install all available Windows Updates, from the command line, on Windows Server 2016 and later, without doing any GUI interactions or using third party script modules.

Surely there must be a simple (or complicated) PowerShell script that can just install all the pending Windows Updates.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a third party PowerShell script you don't want to use and you are asking for a PowerShell script (which is obviously third party again). Instead of asking for another script better look at the script code you and learn how it works. Once you have understood everything it's no longer third party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the machine registry settings are set to get Windows Update from Microsoft via the Internet, here's some logic that can kick start without the native Windows PowerShell module you mention—which works great by the way in my experience.

I've used this successfully against both local and remote machines using `enter-pssession` or `invoke-command` in the past no problem.

### PowerShell

```
$WUServer = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU").UseWUServer;
If ( $WUServer ) { 
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\" -Name "UseWUServer" -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force;
    Restart-Service -Name wuauserv -Force;
    };
usoclient startinteractivescan;
```

If that doesn't do it, you might have to wipe all the Windows Update settings per any policies pointing to WSUS servers, etc. with logic like this instead.

```
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" -Force -Confirm:$false;
Restart-Service -Name wuauserv -Force;
usoclient startinteractivescan;
```

### Supporting Resource

- [Manage additional Windows Update settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wu-settings)

  > ```
  > UseWUServer (REG_DWORD)
  > ```
  >
  > Set this value to `1` to configure Automatic Updates to use a server
  > that is running Software Update Services instead of Windows Update.

Comment: You might have to play with `usoclient startinstall` or `usoclient startdownload` but in my expierence the `usoclient startinteractivescan` kicks off Windows Updates and starts the download and install automatically if it finds any.